# Não é possível ler a propriedade

Tags: jquery

Estou com um problema que parece ser simples, mas que não consigo achar a solução.

```
table = "<div><table class='table table-hover'>";
dados = "";

for(var i = 0; i <= retorno.dados.length; i++)
{
    dados = dados + "<tr><td class='col-md-11'>" + retorno.dados[i]['user_id'] + "    </td>";         
    // console.log(retorno.dados[i]['user_id']);
}
```

O erro no console é o seguinte: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined

Comment: O que dá `console.log(typeof retorno.dados, JSON.stringify(retorno.dados));`?

Comment: No console somente aparece :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined.

Comment: Mas quando dou um alert(retorno.dados[i]['user_id']), ele mostra os dados corretamente.

Comment: Coloca o que perguntei __antes__ da linha `dados = dados + ...`

Comment: Ok, no console deu o seguinte resultado; object [{"user_id":"asdsad","user_admin":"0"},{"user_id":"dasdsadasdasdsad","user_admin":"0"},{"user_id":"dddddddddddddddd","user_admin":"1"},{"user_id":"dsfsdfsdfsdf","user_admin":"0"},{"user_id":"ewrewr","user_admin":"0"},{"user_id":"hgkhjkhjykhjkhj","user_admin":"0"},{"user_id":"jhgjhgjhgjhgj","user_admin":"0"},{"user_id":"oiupipoip","user_admin":"1"},

Comment: Muda de `i<=` para `i<` no ciclo for...

Comment: Ok, agora funcionou, muito obrigado sergio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando percorres uma array com um ciclo `for(var i=0;i<=` tens de parar antes de `i` ser igual ao ultimo elemento da array.

Diz assim [na MDN sobre `.length`:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

> The length property [...]  is always numerically greater than the highest index in the array.

Ou seja, a propriedade `length` é sempre maior que o indice do ultimo elemento da array, por isso não se pode usar `<=`.